# explode an spark array column to multiple columns sparksql

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a column which has type `Value` defined like below

```
val Value: ArrayType = ArrayType(
  new StructType()
  .add("unit", StringType)
  .add("value", StringType)
)
```

and data like this

```
[[unit1, 25], [unit2, 77]]
[[unit2, 100], [unit1, 40]]
[[unit2, 88]]
[[unit1, 33]]
```

I know spark sql can use functions.explode to make the data become multiple rows, but what i want is explode to multiple columns (or the 1 one column but 2 items for the one has only 1 item).

so the end result looks like below

```
unit1 unit2
25  77
40  100
value1 88
33 value2
```

How could I achieve this?

**addtion** after initial post and update
I want to get result like this (this is more like my final goal).

```
transformed-column
[[unit1, 25], [unit2, 77]]
[[unit2, 104], [unit1, 40]]
[[unit1, value1], [unit2, 88]]
[[unit1, 33],[unit2,value2]]
```

where `value1` is the result of applying some kind of map/conversion function using the `[unit2, 88]`
similarly,  `value2` is the result of applying the same map /conversion function using the `[unit1, 33]`

Comment: How is the second row in the result data being calculated? Has the array always only 1 or 2 elements or could be there more?

Comment: @Minnie, shouldn't the expected result be something like `(unit1, unit2): (25, 27), (40, 100), (null, 88), (33, null)`?

Comment: Hi @werner, it is either 1 or 2 items. can not be more. I just realized i had error in my mocked result after carefully reading what you and LeoC said. I've now updated it.

Comment: Hi @LeoC, sorry, you are right, i will upate the expected result.

Comment: to achive my final goal, i actually can have different expected result. I will add it now.

Comment: I suppose your actual data might have more different `unit`s than just two, in which case what will `value1`, `value2`, `value3`, ... be dependent on?

Comment: you can use `map_from_entries` to convert the column into a map and then select the map by keys: unit1 and unit2. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.map_from_entries. BTW. this is a pyspark link, Scala should be the same.

Comment: @Leo C , no it is max 2.

Comment: Hi @jxc, the map_from_entries helped. It worked for java. also, for others who to read this in java, the map returned is scala immutable map, if you want to further process such as using UDF, the method should take scala immutable map as parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using the `map_from_entries` as suggested by @jxc, and then used `UDF` to convert the map of 1 item to map of 2 items, using business logic to convert between the 2 units.

one thing to note is the map returned from `map_from_entries` is scala map. and if you use `java`, need to make sure the udf method takes `scala` map instead.

ps. maybe I did not have to use map_from_entries, instead maybe i could make the `UDF` to take `array` of `structType`